# adb install command when device is not present

Tags: android, adb

I am installing an apk on an android device using the command "adb install" from my application. But if by chance the device is not connected, the install command will indefinitely wait for the device to be connected.

Is there any way to provide a timeout wherein the install command will come out if no device is found within that time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through

Window-> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)